# Is it possible to reverse the orderby results with youtube API?

Tags: php, api, youtube, youtube-api

re: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html#Searching_for_Videos

Im using the `orderby` or as the Zend gdata API calles it `setOrderBy` to get results ranked by viewcount. they are returned in Descending order and I need Ascending. Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get the results into an array, you can then reverse the order by calling array_reverse().

Comment: Well, in this particular search there are 3900+ results. My next attempt was then to use the setStartIndex to get a high number, but the API will not let you request anything over 1000 for some reason. The solution evades me. When I get page by page it caps me off at 800 results.

Comment: I think you may be out of luck for an easy way of doing this.  You could suck in all the information into your own database (adding new items when appropriate).  Then you can query your own database in any way you see fit.

Comment: Agreed. I'll go ahead and mark this answered so it wont be hanging out there.  - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know i'm kinda late, but I'm having the same issue. My approach (if I find out that the API is not offering this) is to simply request the last part by using 'start-index'. it's a little bit annoying, but possible.

```
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='. $query .'author=' . $author;
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
$ind = $sxml->children('http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/')->totalResults;
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='. $query .
             'author='. $author .'orderby=published'.
             '&max-result=100&start-index=' . ($ind-100);
/* save to some array and use. */
```

- If you found an easier way - I'll be happy to know.